# Having issues with Node JS MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm creating a discord bot that pulls from a pre-established database of patch note news I have, it's my first time dealing with NodeJS and MySQL.  I've got the default connection code in the file right now to test the connection and it looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();



const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const mysql = require('mysql');




const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    user: process.env.MYSQLUSER,
    db: process.env.DATABSE,
    password: process.env.MYSQLPASSWORD,
});

con.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected");
})
```

I've tried hosting the application local on my machine with a remote connection to the SQL database and on the actual server that it lives on, so far this is all I'm getting:

```
/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'niemer5_discordbot'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/niemer5/news-bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/niemer5/news-bot/index.js:22:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'niemer5_discordbot'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
}
```

The user exists, it has ALL privileges, I set everything up in cPanel and also tried granting privs in SQL CLI and so far no luck it just errors out with a 1045 access denied error and I have no clue what is happening.  Looking for a little guidance here!

Comment: the error says *"using password: NO"* so check your environment variable for the password if it's correctly set ...

Comment: Not gonna lie, I really thought I set the environment variable name to that, it was just MYSQLPASS, I feel salty about that haha, thanks for the catch.